# Не работает нахождение факториала Python

Tags: python

Не могу понять, почему не работает нахождение факториала, сижу туплю. При положительном вводе выводит 0, при отрицательном и 0 выводит введённое число. Версия - 3.10.4

```
val = int( input('Введите число: ') )
result = val

while val > 0:
    val -= 1
    result *= val

print(result)
```

Comment: Условие нужно поменять `while val >= 2:`. А ноль выводится, потому что `val` обнуляет `result`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while val > 1:
    ...
```

В конце (когда `val = 1`) вы делаете `val -= 1` и получается, что `val = 0`. Тогда `result * 0 = 0`